# MySQL query giving me incorrect or old data

Tags: mysql, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table where the values are like this,

| id | value | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | PENDING |
| 2 | b | COMPLETE |
| 3 | c | INPROGRESS |
| 4 | d | PENDING |
| 5 | e | PENDING |

Now, I have two threads the are trying to do the same thing. They are as follows.

1. Fetch a record from the table that is not INPROGRESS or COMPLETE.
2. Mark it as INPROGRESS.
3. Process the record.
4. Mark it as COMPLETE.

I have implemented the following things to make sure that both the threads are not picking up the same record at the same time.

1. "select * from table where status not in ('COMPLETE', 'INPROGRESS') limit 1 for update" to get a suitable record from the table.
2. Made step 1 and 2 in a single transaction so that the table becomes read locked until the picked up record gets marked as INPROGRESS.

However, I am facing the following issue
If thread-1 is fetching a record and while it's yet to mark the record as 'INPROGRESS', the other thread(thread-2) tries to do the same. Thread-2 sometimes fetches the record that is already picked by thread-1 first and returns the same record with status as 'INPROGRESS' once the lock is lifted by the thread-1 transaction.

I am not able to figure out how to solve the issue other than adding a status value check after the record is fetched but I think there might be a better way of doing this.

Please let me know if there's a better way of doing this.

Here is a sample code of the method responsible for fetching a record to be processed,

// Repository

```
class TableRepository implements JpaRepository<Table, Long> {
 @Query(value = "select * from table where status not in ('COMPLETE', 'INPROGRESS') limit 1 for update", nativeQuery=true)
 Table getOneValidRecord(); 
}
```

// Service class

```
class TableService {

@Autowired
private TableRepository repository;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Table getOneValidRecord() {

Table table = repository.getOneValidRecord();
table.setStatus("INPROGRESS");
return repository.save(table);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use intermediate reserving state. On SQL level:

**Step 1.** Try to reserve.

```sql
UPDATE table
SET status = 'Thread 1 reserved'
WHERE status = 'PENDING'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

**Step 2.** Check does the reservation is successful.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Thread 1 reserved'
```

If the output is zero, then the same row was over-reserved by thread 2. Goto step 1.
If the output is over 1, then emergency situation occures. Call operator.

**Step 3.** Process the row.

```sql
UPDATE table
SET status = 'INPROGRESS'
WHERE status = 'Thread 1 reserved'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I get your approach but won't that be a problem every time if both the thread calls the method at the same time?

Comment: @HindolDey If both threads calls this code at the same time then one thread (A) will overwrite the value set by another thread (B). So A will process whereas B will *If the output is zero, then the same row was over-reserved by thread 2. Goto step 1.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Akina.  But I think this approach might be having more overhead than desired.

Comment: @HindolDey *But I think this approach might be having more overhead than desired.* Additional operation (ensure that the row is reserved for current thread and is not re-reserved) produces additional overhead - does this is strange for you?

Comment: This approach might help with this specific example. But I was hoping to find where or how I was using the  'for update' query in MySQL incorrectly so that I am getting the old data.